# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting this error :

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Why would I get that from this code? How can I get around this ?

```
var $this = $("input");
foob_name = $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
   return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
}));
```

Comment: Remove the last ")".

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but... the `+$1` is a lazy way to convert the string to a number, isn't it? Terrible, if so.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: what's the officially preferred way to do it?

Comment: There's no "official" way, but using `Number(value)` or even `parseInt(value, radix)` is preferred as it _clearly speaks_ what's the intention.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra parenthesis.

The following portion is parsed as an assignment so the interpreter/compiler will look for a semi-colon or attempt to insert one if certain conditions are met.

```
foob_name = $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
   return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
})
```

Answer (score 7):

too many ) parenthesis remove one of them.

Answer (score 4):

Or you might have something like this (redeclaring a variable):

```
var data = [];
var data =
```

Comment: This was the case for me!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, hope this will help someone:

```
const firstName = 'Joe';
const lastName = 'Blogs';
const wholeName = firstName + ' ' lastName + '.';
```

The problem was that I was missing a plus (+) between the empty space and lastName. This is a super simplified example: I was concatenating about 9 different parts so it was hard to spot the error.

Summa summarum: if you get "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement", don't look at what  is wrong with the the semicolon (;) symbols in your code, look for an error in syntax on that line.